# App crashes in android studio when a button is clicked. Appname has stopped working is displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, onclick, crash

This is my xml code. Please help in debugging.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/txtMargins"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/txtMargins"
    android:text="@string/quantityNum"/>


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/txtMargins"
    android:text="@string/Order"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the java code.

```
 package com.example.kartik.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    enter code here
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView=
    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText(number);
    }
    }
```

Please help. Is there a method to prevent app crashing without using the onclick listener. How is the onClick xml attribute different from onClick listener.

Here is the logCat.

```
    --------- beginning of crash
06-11 02:34:18.584 2457-2457/com.example.kartik.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.kartik.myapplication, PID: 2457
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)
                                                                                    at com.example.kartik.myapplication.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                                    at com.example.kartik.myapplication.MainActivity.submitOrder(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Change your line like from,
quantityTextView.setText(number);
to
quantityTextView.setText(number+"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the logCat, the problems lies in:

```
quantityTextView.setText(number);
```

TextView has multiple signatures for setText, and when you send an integer to it, it tries to use:

```
 public final void setText(int resid)
```

and it tries to find a string resource with id 1. To set the text of TextView to integer, you should use convert it to string and set it like that:

```
quantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(number));
```